# What is a term for an instrument that can play any note, even the notes between notes?

Tags: terminology

A piano has only so many notes. You can't really play notes between those notes. Some Indian instruments can play even more notes between those on a piano, I believe called "microtones". There are some instruments though, like the ROLI Seaboard, where players can slide their finger, and reach essentially any note between notes and between those notes, and seamlessly transition from one tone to higher tones, playing every possible tone between. What would this kind of ability within an instrument be called?

Comment: Your question has been answered but I’d just like to point out that instruments with this ability are very common. Every string instrument without frets, (violin, cello, etc.) brass and wind instruments with slides just to name a few are capable of this, not to mention several electronic instruments as well.

Comment: Technically, all instruments that have means to directly control the fine tuning while playing could be considered in this category, with some obvious limitations based on their construction and playing technique (including fretted instruments): the only actual *discrete* pitch instruments are those for which their pitch can only be adjusted in the tuning phase OR have fixed pitch created during manifacturing (such as keyboard based percussions)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Continuous-pitch instrument, as contrasted with discrete-pitch instrument.